# #1054 - Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar, sqldatatypes, mysql-error-1054

I am using MySQL 5.5 and phpmyadmin 3.5.2 (provided by http://www.freewebhostingarea.com)

My sql query is:

```
INSERT INTO `example`(`id`, `name`, `password`) VALUES (1,we,5)
```

where id is int type, name and password are `varchar`.

but when ever inserting any value other than integer in name and age,it displays #1054 error,
i.e

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'we' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must surround any strings with quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `example`(`id`, `name`, `password`) 
VALUES               (1,'User Name','Password123')
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `''` for `we` and probably for `password`:

```
INSERT INTO `example`(`id`, `name`, `password`) VALUES (1,'we','5')
```

because both values are char type.